# Call on class attribute of module of a different file

Tags: python, oop, python-3.6

I have a problem with using a class attribute without calling on that class in a different file when import that module.
I am making a numpy clone and I need to call on attributes in class called Array in file 1 -- numpyClone.py:

```
#file:  numpyClone.py
class Array(object):
def __init__(self,lista=None):
    self.lista = lista
    self.x=[]

def __str__(self):
    return self.__class__.__name__+"("+str(self.lista)+')'

def arange(self,start,stop,step):
    x=self.x
    value=start
    while value<=stop:
        x.append(value)
        value+=step
    return self.__class__(Array(x).lista)
```

and in file 2--test.py I need to be able to import the array function without calling Array as such:

```
import numpyClone as np
print(np.Array([1,2,3])
print(np.arange(1,10,1)
```

which is supposed to return:

```
>>>Array([1, 2]) #works
>>>Array([1, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0]) #does not work, return error: 
#AttributeError: module 'numpyClone' has no attribute 'arange'
```

However, this module does not exist in the directory of the first file. If I was to initiate this in my first file, it would work, However for this assignment I need to import it in the way as I have written above. Hence I cannot do the following:

```
from numpyClone import Array
Array.arrange(1,10,1)
#or
import numpyClone as np
np.Array.arange(1,10,1)
```

I have looked up that there are ways of handling this using the sys library, however we are not allowed to use any libraries other than 'math'. Moreover, I have tried to implement the staticmethod decorator but to no avail. I would be ever so grateful for any sort of help with this so I can proceed with writing the rest of the code.

Comment: This makes no sense. If you don't want `arange` to be a method of Array, don't make it one; then you can import it and use it however you like.

Comment: I wanted to, but this is the requisite of the assignment. It has to be all in the Array class.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. It's impossible for us to tell if `arange` is a method in the `Array` class or if it's supposed to be a top-level function. The latter would make much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

first indent your functions so they can be inside the class and not outside then cut the file and paste it onto your python modules which should have a directory ending in ....\Python\Python36\Lib
then you can do

```
from numpyClone import *
x = Array([1,2,3])
print(x)
print(x.arange(1,4,0.5))
```